# JQuery didn't load by final class config php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code works perfectly, but today when I am started the web app, jQuery is not been loaded; I think I've found the problem, but I haven't understood why it's happenening.

if I try to load by config final class in php, it's don't work, but directly it's work.

The following doesn't:

```
<script src="http://<?php echo Config::Host; ?>/<?php echo Config::SiteName; ?>/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

while this works:

```
<script src="http://localhost/met.com/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

If I try load some images or css stylesheets, it's work perfectly by final config class php

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://<?php echo Config::Host; ?>/<?php echo Config::SiteName; ?>/public/images/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Check the output markup. What is the value in `src`? Is it what you expect? If it is, then are you sure it's still there?

Comment: yes, i check the value of src, and it's show my exactly what i am introduce directly

Comment: If it's exactly the same then I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: the output is http://localhost/met.com/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js